# Nuxt.js Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL - UUID

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

[image]

I have a problem with the nuxt.js pages named **_id.vue** and the url use **uuid**. When I try to access the URL I got this error. How to resolve this?

Comment: Maybe change `_id.vue` to `_uuid.vue` if your are using same param

Comment: I've tried it but it doesn't work

Comment: @AlvinIndra can you share  your `pages` directory structure to understand your current routing convention ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution for this problem

Upgrade version **Nuxt.js** to version **2.14** from **2.10**